# Rust referencing with js-sandbox

Tags: javascript, rust, reference

I am writing a calculator in rust that uses js-sandbox to allow user-scripting for custom functions in javascript

I have a function that takes a mutable reference to an `i32` and returns an `Option` in case of error, I call it `run_js`

I want to create a variable `js_out` and pass the reference to `run_js`, and print it out to prove that the function ran properly

I also have a `main.js` file with the function `fibonacci` which I tested, and it works with nodejs

I am getting the error: `let *output = script.call("fibonacci", &arg)?; expected pattern``

main.rs

```
use js_sandbox::{Script, AnyError};


fn run_js(sname: &str, output: &mut i32) -> Result<(), AnyError> {
    let mut script = Script::from_file(sname).expect("File can be loaded");
    let arg = 6;
    let *output = script.call("fibonacci", &arg)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), AnyError> {
    println!("SCalc version 0.1.0");

    let mut js_out: i32 = 0;

    run_js("src/main.js", &mut js_out)?;

    println!("output: {}", js_out);
    Ok(())
}
```

main.js

```
function fibonacci(length, startNums=[0, 1]) {
    for (var i = 1; i < length-1; i++) {
        startNums.push(startNums[i-1]+startNums[i]);
    }
    return startNums[startNums.length-1];
}

console.log(fibonacci(6));
```

Comment: `let` introduces a new variable, but you just want to assign to an existing variable (through a reference). Just do `*output = ...;`

Comment: thank you so much, I have no idea why I put that there lol